# Transitioning the CSS height property causes "wiggling" in Blisk

Tags: css, css-transitions

I need to animate the height property upon hovering of a few`<li>` items. They are flexbox items centered vertically. In their normal state, they have a set height and everything looks good. In their hovered state, however, when I try to transition their height to a new value, they wiggle up and down. But only in Blisk. That's weird.

I have a demo fiddle to demonstrate this behavior. Here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/ehdk2tj3/.

The issue can be reproduced in Blisk 11.0.157.186. However, in Chrome 72.0.3626.121, Opera 58.0.3135.107 and FF 65.0.1 works as I expect it to.

Is this some weird Blisk-related issue that I can safely ignore, since Blisk is not a general purpose browser?

Apart from the fiddle, I am also providing the same code that reproduces the issue below;

The HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
ul {
  display: flex; align-items: center;
}
li {
  display: flex; align-items: center;
  height: 125px;
  transition: height 350ms;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  list-style: none;
}
li:hover {
  height: 75px;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

I expected the `<li>`s to 'shrink' nice and cleanly- not to bounce up and down continuously until everything sets to its final state.

Comment: Actually it also wiggle on chrome  73.0.3683.86

Comment: @Spyros the link will visible without jumping up and down right?

Comment: @Francisaskquestion I just updated to 73.0.3683.86 (on Windows 10) and the fiddle works OK, no wiggling. Maybe it is platform-dependent?

Comment: I really don't know too. But it was fixed so never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the `padding` instead of `height` to align the list. And also removed the `flex` used `inline-block` to avoid shrinking on hover. I hope this solution will support for all browsers.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
}

li:hover {
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    padding: 15px 5px 20px;
}

li {
    transition: padding 350ms;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    align-self: center;
    padding: 25px 5px 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```